# Having trouble building a navigation mesh getting an empty navmesh

Tags: mesh, game-engine

I am trying to build a navmesh based on this object and it always returns me an empty navmesh. I alredy tryed to change the collision type to navmesh but it doesn't seem to work, the object that I set to follow path is not doing it right. It was supposed to do what is on the second image.
Any advice?
[image: Mesh]
[image: Path]

Answer (score 0):

Guess I needed to scale a bit more the object I was using to generate the navegation mesh, everything is working now.